# ExpressionSet subsetting

Tags: r, expression, bioconductor

I have an `ExpressionSet` object that I want to subset. For example,

```
> str(ESet)
Formal class 'ExpressionSet' [package "Biobase"] ..
  ..@ assayData        :..         
  ..@ phenoData        :
  .. .. .. ..$ STATUS  : num [1:210] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ....
```

I want to extract a subset where `STATUS==0`. I've tried:

```
exprs(ESet@phenoData$STATUS==0)
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Guessing at your data structure, I think the following should work:

```
exprs(ESet)[ESet@phenoData$STATUS==0,]
```

If you look at this [paper](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ncsg3/microarray/), there are lots of examples of sub-setting the data depending on strain and time. I should admit that I'm an author on this paper.

Comment: @Joris: I'm always a bit embarrassed about self promotion - I'm British after all - but when I analysed my first microarray data set, I wish I had a similar paper to look at.

Comment: Use `ESet$STATUS == 0`; see the [Biobase landing page](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biobase.html) and "An Introduction to Biobase and ExpressionSet" section "ExpressionSet basics", in addition to `?ExpressionSet`.

Comment: @csgillespie : Could you please update the link, the old one seems to be dead