# Subset by samples for an ExpressionSet object

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have an ExpressionSet object with 100 samples:

```
> length(sampleNames(eset1))
100
```

I also have a vector of the **names** of 75 samples (not the data itself):

```
> length(vecOf75)
75
```

How can I subset `eset1` (and save it) according to the 75 sample names? That is, I want to disregard those samples in `eset1` whose names are not listed in `vecOf75`. Bear in mind that some of the samples corresponding to the 75 sample names may not be in `eset1`. Thus,

```
> length(sampleNames(eset1))
```

should now give something <75.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An ExpressionSet can be subset like a matrix, so maybe

```
eset2 = eset1[, sampleNames(eset1) %in% vecOf75]
```

or if `all(vecOf75 %in% sampleNames(eset1))` then just

```
eset1[, vecOf75]
```

Not sure what 'save' means; either save(eset2, "some_file.rda") or extracting the components `exprs(eset2)`, `pData(eset2)` etc., and using `write.table` and other standard R functions.

Comment: By 'save', I meant to update `eset1` with its subset rather than create a new RData object such as `eset2`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`eset1 <- vecOf75[vecOf75 %in% eset1]` This says, save to eset1 those of vecOf75 where vecOf75 is in eset1

A trivial example using numbers:

```
eset1 <- sample(1:100)
vecOf75 <- sample(1:200,75)
eset1 <- vecOf75[vecOf75 %in% eset1]
```

Alternatively, you could use `subset()` but, getting used to subsetting via ']' is much more useful programmatically.

`subset(vecOf75, vecOf75 %in% eset1)`

Comment: That won't work with ExpressionSet objects (Bioconductor package).

Comment: If you look at the object in more depth `str(obj)`, I'm sure you can find where the character names are stored and adjust the code above with a few vecof75[vecOf75$storage %in% eset1$storage] or something of that nature.

Comment: Also, `vecOf75` only contains the names of the columns (or samples for an ExpressionSet object). It does not contain the actual data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the object. However, the method is the same. Inside each of those variables is some set of elements that you want to compare. You have to delve into the object and decide which variable you want to subset by. The method x <- x[x %in% y] will remain the same.

Comment: Pretty much what they've done here, as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593931/expressionset-subsetting